# The calling thread must be STA when creating rectangles

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I tried creating a rectangle in a wpf application and I'm recieving this error I tried googling it but it didn't work.

Error:

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

namespace Game
{
    class Engine
    {
        #region Members

        private Thread _render;

        #endregion

        public Engine()
        {
            _render = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Render));
            _render.Start();
        }

        private void Render()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I think this would fix it:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
DispatcherPriority.Background,
new Action(() => this.progressBar.Value = 50));
```

But doesn't that take away the purpose of using a different thread because then all the rendering would still be done on the main thread.

And another question:

I'm trying to draw rectangles of 1 by 1 and detect collision if they "fall" on each other(a loop sets their x--).
Could I also do this with pixels?

Comment: only the main thread can draw multiple threads are only for calculations drawing can only be on the main thread.

Comment: Rendering should always be performed on the main thread. That is a design thing in Windows / Win32.

Comment: Thread creating UI controls must always be STA. Try adding  _render.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); before _render.Start()

Comment: Your code is going the wrong direction. It is not a WPF mindset. In WPF land you want to retain your objects and update the properties on them as necessary. You don't do render passes in WPF, which is contrary to many a game engine philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering should always be performed on the main thread. That is a design thing in Windows / Win32.

Thanks to the original design of Win32 (which involves handles to windows, aka hWnd's), the thread calling the painting operation must be the same as the one doing the actual painting.

There is a nice article on MSDN about the [Threading model and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).